# how to post on friends' walls using php sdk?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i am trying to post to my friends' feeds using this code, but it is not working . i am stuck, any help ??

```
 $app_url ="http://localhost.local/PMS/facebook/PostWithPHP.php";

 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'APPID',
'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
'cookie' => true,
));


  // Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {

$user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
sort($user_friends['data']);

try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$vars = array(
     'message' => 'My Message',
     'name' => 'title',
     'caption' => 'Caption',
     'link' => 'Link',
     'description' => 'Description',
     'picture' => 'image'
);

foreach($user_friends['data'] as $f){
        $sendTo = $f['id'];
        $sendToName = $f['name'];

        $result = $facebook->api("/".$sendTo ."/feed", 'post', $vars);
    }
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
   }
  }

 // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=> $app_url));
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo     "top.location.href = '{$loginUrl}';";
  echo "</script>";
}
```

and another question is that using this code, but with replacing $facebook->api("/".$sendTo ."/feed", 'post', $vars); by $facebook->api("/me/feed", 'post', $vars); and of course without looping friends, posts on my timeline. how can i make it post on my wall ??

Answer (score 0):

I guess for a post to a timeline you will need an accessToken from the user where to publish the content. In your case you just have the accessToken of the registered user, not of his friends. That is a restriction by FB I think.

Comment: mm makes sense,so you think there is no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1st check you getting the user id(place echo and check) if not try this... I think this  will help you brother

```
 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" ."client_id=" . $app_id ."&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
   "&grant_type=client_credentials";

 $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"]; 
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
  $user_id = $data["user_id"];
```

Comment: but i have the user ID , if i echo the $sendTo and $sendToName , i see  all my friends names and IDs .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First of all, make sure the `link` and `picture` parameters for the post are valid URLs. Facebook will give you a error message otherwise (`(#100) link URL is not properly formatted`). Also, the `link` must go to the Canvas or Site URL for your application.

That should solve the issues with posting to a friend's wall.

However, may I remind you that your application is in violation of the Facebook Platform Policy. Facebook doesn't allow multiple posts to the stream (whether its yours or a friends) unless there is explicit permission from the user. It also to stop common friends seeing the same message from multiple friends.

Comment: My Link and Picture parameters are correct, i just changed them here in the question. so you mean this code is correct and should be able to post on 1 friend wall at a time (without looping friends)? but it is not doing that ! :(

Comment: Try posting to a friend's wall using the Graph Tool. It will give you an ID of the post of it worked, or an error message.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

It could help you identify the issue. Facebook also has limits in place for preventing spread of spam using stream_publish.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tutorial here:
https://www.webniraj.com/2012/11/22/facebook-api-posting-a-status-update/

But, instead of making a API call to: `/me/feed`, you replace `me` with the friend's User ID, so it looks like `/12345/feed`

Please note that Facebook has now disabled posting to Friends' walls via the API. Instead, you should either tag the user in an action or use the Requests API.